# Why Powershell Array of Array display different content if not assign to a variable

Tags: powershell

If a cmdlet returns array of array, for example:

```
function test() {
    $results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $array = @()
    for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt 3; $idx++) {
         $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "key1" = "value1";
         }
        $array += @($obj)
    }
    [Void] $results.add($array)
    return ,$results.TOArray()
}
```

Then the output is different when the return value is assigned.

if run `test` directly it displays:

```
test


Length         : 3
LongLength     : 3
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {@{key1=value1}, @{key1=value1}, @{key1=value1}}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 3
```

while assign to a variable:

```
$result = test
$result

key1  
----  
value1
value1
value1
```

And if a cmdlet returns a one level array, the output of `test` and `$(test)` is the same.

```
function test() {
    $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt 3; $idx++) {
         $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            "key1" = "value1";
         }
        $array += @($obj)
    }
    return ,$array
}
```

`test`'s output:

```
key1  
----  
value1
value1
value1
```

Comment: Take away the comma in `return ,$results.ToArray()` and `test` will return the exact same thing as when you assign it to a variable. The comma adds the array you get with `$results.ToArray()` in a new array with one element. Powershell unravels (flattens) this when assigning to a variable. What you see as output from just running `test` are the array properties of that new array created using the comma.

Comment: It is expression vs. command thing: `(test)` is an expression, but `test` is a command.

Comment: @Theo but if comma is removed, the result is an array of psobject but not an array of array. That is not what is expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) has provided the crucial pointer in a terse comment:

The **difference in output rendering** comes down to the fact that:

- **statement `test` is a *command*** (a call to a function, cmdlet, or external program)
- whereas **`$result` (which previously captured `test`'s output) is an *expression*** (something involving only variable references, PowerShell's operators and .NET method calls, outside a pipeline - though it may contain *nested* commands).

By outputting `, $results.ToArray()` from your `test` function (a function is one form of a command), you're using `,`, the array-construction operator, to wrap `$results.ToArray()` (which results in array of arrays) in an *auxiliary, transitory* single-element array, which is a common technique to ensure that a collection is passed on as a *single object* rather than having *its elements enumerated*.

That is, **the aux. wrapper array** is:

- ***invariably lost* on output to the pipeline**, due to the pipeline's automatic unwrapping (unrolling) behavior,
- but it **ensures that the *wrapped* array is seen as a *single object* by the next command in the pipeline**.

The conceptually clearer, but more verbose equivalent of `, $results.ToArray()` inside your function is `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $results.ToArray()`; that is, PowerShell's usually implicit output is made explicit, with a request to suppress the default behavior of *enumerating* output collections.

Given that there is no additional command in the pipeline, `tests` output is implicitly printed to the *screen*.
In the case at hand, printing an array of arrays *as a single object* results in the property-list output formatting you saw.

By contrast, **`$result`, due to being an *expression* is *implicitly enumerated***. That is, the array of arrays captured from `test` - without the aux. wrapper array! - is sent *one element at a time* to the output-formatting system, and these elements then render more meaningfully.

---

To provide a **simpler example**:

Assume your function `test` uses `return , , (1..3)` to output a container array containing a 3-element array that is finally wrapped in an aux. single-element array (as an aside: `return` in PowerShell is just syntactic sugar for *exiting* a function or script block, it has no direct relationship with what is *output*).

Executing the `test` function is then the equivalent of direct execution of the following *expression*:

```
, , (1..3)
```

That is, the outer, aux. array is again discarded due to implicit enumeration and `, (1..3)` is rendered as a *single object*, resulting in the property-list format:

```
Length         : 3
LongLength     : 3
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {1, 2, 3}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 3
```

By contrast, executing `$result` (after running `$result = test`) is then the equivalent of just:

```
, (1..3)
```

That is, the outer, aux. array was lost during `$result = test`, the container array too is now implicitly enumerated, and `(1..3)` as a single object renders more meaningfully (you can't visually distinguish it from sending `1..3` directly to the pipeline, i.e., element by element):

```
1
2
3
```

---

#### How arrays are formatted for display

When a command or expression is neither captured in a variable nor sent to the pipeline to another command nor redirected (with `>` or `>>`), it is implicitly printed to the screen (host), using PowerShell's default output-formatting system.

You can think of a command such as:

```
test
```

being the equivalent of<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
test | Out-Host
```

`Out-Host` automatically chooses a `Format-*` cmdlet to use for rendering that is suitable for the input at hand, based on the first input object:
If that object has 4 or fewer properties, `Format-Table` is chosen; otherwise, it is `Format-List`.

However, if that first input object is a *collection* (implements `IEnumerable`), it is that collection's *first element* that the choice of formatting cmdlet is based on (as opposed to the collection type as a whole), and the collection's elements are formatted individually using that cmdlet.

In the case of your `$result` variable getting output, the input array's first element is a `[pscustomobject]` instance (created with `New-Object PSObject`) with 1 property, `key1`; therefore, `Format-Table` is chosen, and the [pscustomobject]` instances that make up the array are shown in a tabular format.

By contrast, in the case of your `test` call, the input array's first element is *another array*, which is itself *not* further enumerated. `Get-Member -InputObject (1,2) -Type Property` reveals that an array has 8 properties (`Count`, `IsFixedSize`, `IsReadOnly`, `IsSynchronized`, `Length`, `LongLength`, `Rank`, `SyncRoot`), which is why `Format-List` is chosen, listing each property as a name / value pair on its own line.

Of course, you can opt to use a formatting cmdlet *explicitly*, and PetSerAl points out that the formatting cmdlets support the `-Expand` parameter, which gives you control over how input objects that are collections are formatted: you can ask to have the collection enumerated, i.e., to print *its elements* (`-Expand EnumOnly`, which is the default), to show just the collection's own properties, without printing its elements (`-Expand CoreOnly`), or both (`-Expand Both`).

Note, however, that you cannot request *additional* levels of enumeration via `-Expand`, so your `test` output cannot be directly formatted to show the individual elements of your nested array.
However, it is trivial to make that happen by piping to `Write-Output`, which performs the additional level of enumeration required to render the elements individually:

```
test | Write-Output
```

---

<sup>[1] More accurately, as PetSerAl points out, it is:  `. { test } 2>&1 | Out-Default`, enabling users to override the `Out-Default` cmdlet for custom formatting.</sup>