# Same array content, giving me different results

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

**Summary of issue**

I have two variables with the same content, the only difference is how the variable was populated, when i try to use it in exchange management shell i get for one variable an error while the other one works as it should be.

**Long explanation - With examples**

I created a transport rule to block emails from specific senders, I'm trying to  use one line in powershell to add users the the block list.

1. I tried first the regular way to manipulate an array using
   `set-transportrule -identity "whatever" -from @{add="whoever"}`
   But this doesn't work, i researched it and saw that it's by design, so i gave up on this.
2. So I tried something else
   `set-transportrule -identity "whatever" -from (get-transportrule -identity "whatever").from,"whoever2"`
   But i again hit a road block.
3. So tried `set-transportrule -identity "whatever" -from "whoever1","whoever2"` and it worked beautifully. But this is not what i want I'm trying to add to the existing values.

This got me thinking, so i started testing to find the differences between the two arrays

1. First I created a variable `variable1 = "whoever1","whoever2"` and used it like this `set-transportrule -identity "whatever" -from $variable1` and it worked as it should be.
2. So I went ahead and created another variable `variable2 = (get-transportrule -identity "whatever").from,"whoever2"` and tried using it `set-transportrule -identity "whatever" -from $variable2`, but this didn't work.

I compared the variable types and they are identical. Whats going on here? What am i missing

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: did you compare the array item types or the arrays? `$Collection.GetType()` is not going to give you the same result as `$Collection[0].GetType()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to *concatenate* two arrays *flatly*, you must use `+`:

```
set-transportrule -identity "whatever" `
                  -from ((get-transportrule -identity "whatever").from + "whoever2")
```

<sup>Note: Since operator `+` can only be used in an *expression*, the entire `-from` argument must be enclosed in `(...)`.</sup>

By contrast, `<array>, <scalar>` creates a *2-element* array whose 1st element is `<array>`, and whose 2nd element is `<scalar>`, which is not your intent.

`,`, which is PowerShell's array-construction operator, creates an array with each operand becoming an array element *as-is*, whether a given operand is a scalar or an array.

By contrast, with an array-valued LHS, `+` *concatenates* the LHS and RHS, by appending the RHS element(s) as additional elements to the LHS (which implicitly creates a *new* array, given that arrays are fixed-size).

---

A simplified example:

```
$arr = 1, 2   # input array
$scalar = 3   # scalar to append

# INCORRECT: Creates *nested* array.
($arr, $scalar).Count # -> 2(!); [0] of the new array contains $arr, [1] $scalar
# Same as: (1, 2), 3

# CORRECT: Creates *flat* array.
($arr + $scalar).Count # -> 3
# Same as: (1, 2) + 3 == 1, 2, 3
```

Note that you can't tell the difference between `$arr, $scalar` and `$arr + $scalar` by how they *print to the screen*, because the implicit output formatting implicitly enumerates an array received as a single input object.

You can make the difference visible by piping to `Format-Table` with `-Expand CoreOnly`, which suppresses the implicit enumeration and instead prints the properties of any array element itself:

```
# Flat array: prints as expected.
PS> $arr + $scalar | Format-Table -Expand CoreOnly
1
2
3

# Array with sub-arrays: output reveals the presence of subarrays
PS> $arr, $scalar | Format-Table -Expand CoreOnly

Length LongLength Rank SyncRoot IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized Count
------ ---------- ---- -------- ---------- ----------- -------------- -----
     2          2    1 {1, 2}        False        True          False     2
3
```

For additional information, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54169963/45375).